# tips how to pass N5

Tags: jlpt

I just started studying Nihongo, and I aim to take the JLPT n5 exam after 5 months, but at that moment I would just finish 2 modules.

Any tips, strategies and advices on how to learn fast and how to pass the exam.

Thanks.

Comment: This Link will help you with finding learning resources http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese

Comment: Oh that's a whole bunch, it's overwhelming, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I heard, N5 is very easy.
However, if you really are starting from an absolute zero, 5 months might still be hard unless you are willing to put the time.(1-3 hours per day)
Make sure you master all your kana and about 100-200 of the most basic and used kanji. Work on basic sentence structure and conjugation and you will be fine.

If you work very hard, N3 is a realistic goal for 1 year of study.

There are many learning tricks which I am sure you can find all over the web. But I would suggest listening to Japanese music/podcast every second you can afford. Audio courses like pimsleur can be very useful too. As for learning kana and kanji, just spam flash cards on an application of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My target is only N4, I'll want to take two exams this year, I am also trying to study learn 3 hours a day.